# Maven plugin execution ID

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have a simple question about execution ID in maven plugin.

```
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>gwt-process-resources</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>i18n</goal>
            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Can someone explain to me what does this executionId does? How are goals triggered? Can I call directly the "gwt-process-resources" in order to execute both goals? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<id></id>` exists only for you to be able to distinguish between other executions. This tag will be displayed when you do the actual build.

Your execution example will invoke the two goals you have specified: `i18n` and `generateAsync`.

If the plugin isn't bound to a specific *phase* (`process-resources`, `package`, `install`, etc) your execution will not performed. The plugin's documentation should tell if this is the case.

You can specify/override the default phase by using the `<phase`> tag:

```
...
<execution>
  <id>gwt-process-resources</id>
  <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- If you need to override -->
  <goals>
    <goal>i18n</goal>
    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
...
```

...

Goals are either triggered:

- Automatically (implicitly by their default phase or explicitly as above)
- By command line execution: `mvn <plugin name>:<goal>`

Comment: Ok thank you for this clarification !
The primary thing I was missing is "Automatically (implicitly by their default phase ....)" the "i18n" goal and "generateAsync" are not trigger if not written in the pom .. and they are trigger because they both have a default execution phase !

    `<mojo>
      <goal>i18n</goal>
      .....
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      ....
   </mojo>`

Thanks :)

Comment: Can we give any custom name as id to execution ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Unless it matches an id from an inherited execution of the same plugin, in which case your execution will override the parent’s. The id is just a string, but the convention is to separate words with a hyphen.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, since [Maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html) you can, but you need to explicitly execute each goal. There are a couple of ways.

This works always:

`mvn <group-id>:<artifact-id>:(<version>):<goal>@<execution-id>`

in your case:

`mvn org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:i18n@gwt-process-resources` (you can skip the version)

The other (more convenient) way is by using the short name of the goals, as found at the top of the [plugin page](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/i18n-mojo.html):

`mvn gwt:i18n@gwt-process-resources`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple explanation:

**You can not call excecution ids directly**

```
  mvn gwt-process-resources
```

will not work since *gwt-process-resources* is just an id.

If there is no `<phase>` declaration in the pom then you might want to look at the documentation of the plugin and find the corresponding default phase. If you look at the [documentation of the gwt plugin](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html):

- gwt:i18n Binds by default to   generate-sources.
- gwt:generateAsync Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-sources.

**How are goals triggered?**

if you do

```
mvn compile
```

=> compile > generate-sources in maven lifecycle
=> maven execute gwt:i18n after gwt:generateAsync
=> executed in the order they are declared in pom.xml because  they are bound to some phase "generate-sources"

Comment: That's a great explanation, my maven-knowledge was missing the "binds by default" feature of some plugin's goals :)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that while execution id's have to be unique among all executions of a single plugin within a POM, they don't have to be unique across an inheritance hierarchy of POMs. Executions of the same id from different POMs are merged. The same applies to executions that are defined by profiles.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins (e.g., compile plugin) will use the "id" in a temporary file name.  Therefore, when changing the "id" ensure you don't use characters like ":" that could cause problems formatting a valid file name path.